# Newbie Scala question about simple math array operations

Tags: scala

Newbie Scala Question:

Say I want to do this [Java code] in Scala:

```
public static double[] abs(double[] r, double[] im) {
  double t[] = new double[r.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < t.length; ++i) {
    t[i] = Math.sqrt(r[i] * r[i] + im[i] * im[i]);
  }
  return t;
}
```

and also make it generic (since Scala efficiently do generic primitives I have read).  Relying only on the core language (no library objects/classes, methods, etc), how would one do this?  Truthfully I don't see how to do it at all, so I guess that's just a pure bonus point question.

I ran into sooo many problems trying to do this simple thing that I have given up on Scala for the moment. Hopefully once I see the Scala way I will have an 'aha' moment.

UPDATE:
Discussing this with others, this is the best answer I have found so far.

```
def abs[T](r: Iterable[T], im: Iterable[T])(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
   import n.mkNumericOps                                                   
   r zip(im) map(t => math.sqrt((t._1 * t._1 + t._2 * t._2).toDouble))          
}
```

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by indirection... Except for this one problem" ;)

Comment: See my answer below for the *almost generic* solution. It fails because there is no `sqrt` defined for an arbitrary `Numeric` type

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Especially useful to learn about this zipped function, and also implicitly. Unfortunately it appears that generics in Scala are pretty complicated.  Ironically it seems C++ templates are simpler.

Comment: I was hesitant to ask this question as I thought might be a 'stupid' question.  Turns out it is actually fairly difficult and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doing generic/performant primitives in scala actually involves two related mechanisms which scala uses to **avoid boxing/unboxing** (e.g. wrapping an `int` in a `java.lang.Integer` and vice versa):

- `@specialize` type annotations
- Using `Manifest` with arrays

[`specialize`](http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/9) is an annotation that tells the Java compiler to create "primitive" versions of code (akin to C++ templates, so I am told). Check out the type declaration of [`Tuple2`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//library/scala/Tuple2.scala#L1) (which is specialized) compared with [`List`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1) (which isn't). It was added in **2.8** and means that, for example code like `CC[Int].map(f : Int => Int)` is executed without ever boxing any `int`s (assuming `CC` is specialized, of course!).

`Manifest`s are a way of doing *reified* types in scala (which is limited by the JVM's *type erasure*). This is particularly useful when you want to have a method genericized on some type `T` and then create an array of `T` (i.e. `T[]`) within the method. In Java this is not possible because `new T[]` is illegal. In scala this is possible using Manifests. In particular, and in this case it allows us to construct a *primitive* T-array, like `double[]` or `int[]`. (This is awesome, in case you were wondering)

*Boxing is so important from a performance perspective because it creates garbage, unless all of your `int`s are < 127. It also, obviously, adds a level of indirection in terms of extra process steps/method calls etc. But consider that you probably don't give a hoot unless you are absolutely positively sure that you definitely do (i.e. most code does not need such micro-optimization)*

---

So, back to the question: in order to do this with no boxing/unboxing, you must use `Array` (`List` is not specialized yet, and would be more object-hungry anyway, even if it were!). The `zipped` function on a pair of collections will return a collection of `Tuple2`s (which will not require boxing, as this *is* specialized).

In order to do this generically (i.e. across various numeric types) you must require a context bound on your generic parameter that it is `Numeric` and that a `Manifest` can be found (required for array creation). So I started along the lines of...

```
def abs[T : Numeric : Manifest](rs : Array[T], ims : Array[T]) : Array[T] = {
    import math._
    val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
    (rs, ims).zipped.map { (r, i) => sqrt(num.plus(num.times(r,r), num.times(i,i))) }
    //                               ^^^^ no SQRT function for Numeric
}
```

...but it *doesn't quite work*. The reason is that a "generic" `Numeric` value does not have an operation like `sqrt` -> so you could only do this at the point of knowing you had a `Double`. For example:

```
scala> def almostAbs[T : Manifest : Numeric](rs : Array[T], ims : Array[T]) : Array[T] = {
 | import math._
 | val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
 | (rs, ims).zipped.map { (r, i) => num.plus(num.times(r,r), num.times(i,i)) }
 | }
almostAbs: [T](rs: Array[T],ims: Array[T])(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T],implicit     evidence$2: Numeric[T])Array[T]
```

Excellent - now see this purely generic method do some stuff!

```
scala> val rs = Array(1.2, 3.4, 5.6); val is = Array(6.5, 4.3, 2.1)
rs: Array[Double] = Array(1.2, 3.4, 5.6)
is: Array[Double] = Array(6.5, 4.3, 2.1)

scala> almostAbs(rs, is)
res0: Array[Double] = Array(43.69, 30.049999999999997, 35.769999999999996)
```

Now we can `sqrt` the result, because we have a `Array[Double]`

```
scala> res0.map(math.sqrt(_))
res1: Array[Double] = Array(6.609841147864296, 5.481788029466298, 5.980802621722272)
```

And to prove that this would work even with another `Numeric` type:

```
scala> import math._
import math._
scala> val rs = Array(BigDecimal(1.2), BigDecimal(3.4), BigDecimal(5.6)); val is =     Array(BigDecimal(6.5), BigDecimal(4.3), BigDecimal(2.1))
rs: Array[scala.math.BigDecimal] = Array(1.2, 3.4, 5.6)
is: Array[scala.math.BigDecimal] = Array(6.5, 4.3, 2.1)

scala> almostAbs(rs, is)
res6: Array[scala.math.BigDecimal] = Array(43.69, 30.05, 35.77)

scala> res6.map(d => math.sqrt(d.toDouble))
res7: Array[Double] = Array(6.609841147864296, 5.481788029466299, 5.9808026217222725)
```

Comment: I think `@specialize` is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 11):

Use `zip` and `map`:

```
scala> val reals = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
reals: List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)

scala> val imags = List(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)
imags: List[Double] = List(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)

scala> reals zip imags
res0: List[(Double, Double)] = List((1.0,1.5), (2.0,2.5), (3.0,3.5))

scala> (reals zip imags).map {z => math.sqrt(z._1*z._1 + z._2*z._2)}
res2: List[Double] = List(1.8027756377319946, 3.2015621187164243, 4.6097722286464435)

scala> def abs(reals: List[Double], imags: List[Double]): List[Double] =
     | (reals zip imags).map {z => math.sqrt(z._1*z._1 + z._2*z._2)}
abs: (reals: List[Double],imags: List[Double])List[Double]

scala> abs(reals, imags)
res3: List[Double] = List(1.8027756377319946, 3.2015621187164243, 4.6097722286464435)
```

**UPDATE**

It is better to use `zipped` because it avoids creating a temporary collection:

```
scala> def abs(reals: List[Double], imags: List[Double]): List[Double] =
     | (reals, imags).zipped.map {(x, y) => math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)}
abs: (reals: List[Double],imags: List[Double])List[Double]

scala> abs(reals, imags)
res7: List[Double] = List(1.8027756377319946, 3.2015621187164243, 4.6097722286464435)
```

Comment: Instead of java.lang.Math.sqrt() you can use simply math.sqrt()

Comment: Also, `List` is **not specialized** so your answer does not avoid boxing

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a easy way in Java to create generic numeric computational code; the libraries aren't there as you can see from oxbow's answer.  Collections also are designed to take arbitrary types, which means that there's an overhead in working with primitives with them.  So the fastest code (without careful bounds checking) is either:

```
def abs(re: Array[Double], im: Array[Double]) = {
  val a = new Array[Double](re.length)
  var i = 0
  while (i < a.length) {
    a(i) = math.sqrt(re(i)*re(i) + im(i)*im(i))
    i += 1
  }
  a
}
```

or, tail-recursively:

```
def abs(re: Array[Double], im: Array[Double]) = {
  def recurse(a: Array[Double], i: Int = 0): Array[Double] = {
    if (i < a.length) {
      a(i) = math.sqrt(re(i)*re(i) + im(i)*im(i))
      recurse(a, i+1)
    }
    else a
  }
  recurse(new Array[Double](re.length))
}
```

So, unfortunately, this code ends up not looking super-nice; the niceness comes once you package it in a handy complex number array library.

If it turns out that you don't actually need highly efficient code, then

```
def abs(re: Array[Double], im: Array[Double]) = {
  (re,im).zipped.map((i,j) => math.sqrt(i*i + j*j))
}
```

will do the trick compactly and conceptually clearly (once you understand how `zipped` works).  The penalty in my hands is that this is about 2x slower.  (Using `List` makes it 7x slower than while or tail recursion in my hands; `List` with `zip` makes it 20x slower; generics with arrays are 3x slower even without computing the square root.)

(Edit: fixed timings to reflect a more typical use case.)

Comment: This seems the simplest approach and is a (rare?) case where it is less elegant than Java.  Thanks also for the benchmarking.  Useful information.

Comment: @indirection - Yes, it is one of the cases where the performance/elegance curve went to the elegance side (at least initially; hopefully eventually we'll have both).

Answer (score 1):

**After Edit:**

OK I have got running what I wanted to do. Will take two Lists of any type of number and return an Array of Doubles.

```
def abs[A](r:List[A], im:List[A])(implicit numeric: Numeric[A]):Array[Double] = {
  var t = new Array[Double](r.length)
  for( i <- r.indices) {          
    t(i) = math.sqrt(numeric.toDouble(r(i))*numeric.toDouble(r(i))+numeric.toDouble(im(i))*numeric.toDouble(im(i)))
  }
  t
}
```

Comment: Useful.   I didn't know about r.indices and I need something like that all the time.