# what's the conceptual purpose of the Tuple2?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

take this as a follow up to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656005/newbie-scala-question-about-simple-math-array-operations/3656941#3656941)

I'm new to scala and working through the [99 problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/). The given solution to p9 is:

```
object P09 {
  def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
    if (ls.isEmpty) List(List())
    else {
      val (packed, next) = ls span { _ == ls.head }
      if (next == Nil) List(packed)
      else packed :: pack(next)
    }
  }
}
```

The [span function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@span%28p:A=%3EBoolean%29:%28List%5BA%5D,List%5BA%5D%29) is doing all the work here. As you can see from the API doc (it's the link) span returns a Tuple2 (actually the doc says it returns a pair - but that's been deprecated in favor or Tuple2). I was trying to figure out why you don't get something back like a list-of-lists or some such thing and stumbled across the SO link above. As I understand it, the reason for the Tuple2 has to do with increasing performance by not having to deal with Java's 'boxing/unboxing' of things like ints into objects like Integers. My question is

1) is that an accurate statement?

2) are there other reasons for something like span to return a Tuple2?

thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `TupleN` object has at least two major differences when compared to a "standard" `List`+:

- (less importantly) the size of the tuple is known beforehand, allowing to better reason about it (by the programmer and the compiler).
- (more importantly) a tuple **preserves the type information** for each of its elements/"slots".

Note that, as alluded, the type `Tuple2` is a part of the `TupleN` family, all utilizing the same concept. For example:

```
scala> ("1",2,3l)
res0: (String, Int, Long) = (1,2,3)

scala> res0.getClass
res1: Class[_ <: (String, Int, Long)] = class scala.Tuple3
```

As you can see here, each of the elements in the 3-tuple has a distinct type, allowing for better pattern matching, stricter type protection etc.

+*heterogeneous lists are also possible in Scala, but, so far, they're not part of the standard library, and arguably harder to understand, especially for newcomers.*

Comment: w00t! this helps a lot - t/y!!

Comment: Known size and known types for each values.

Answer (score 3):

`span` returns exactly two values. A `Tuple2` can hold exactly two values. A list can contain arbitrarily many values. Therefore `Tuple2` is just a better fit than using a list.

Comment: is there a concern that some how a caller will implement span incorrectly if the return type is List?

Comment: @DavidDaedalus What do you mean, the caller will implement `span`? `span` is already implemented, the caller calls span.

Comment: sorry - 'caller' was probably a poor word choice. i was wondering if there was some technical advantage to not just using a list. your statement is that Tuple2 is 'just a better fit' - in what way? It's not like a we're shipping something and deciding whether or not to put a pair of sneakers in a shoebox or a refrigerator box, right?

Comment: @DavidDaedalus It's a better fit in the sense that a tuple2 can represent exactly those values that might be returned by `span`, whereas a list can represent all other kinds of values like, say, an empty list or a list with three elements. So if `span` would return a list, you could write something like `bla.span(...)(3)` and get an out of bounds error at runtime, while writing `bla.span(...)._3` simply does not compile at all. Similarly pattern matching against `(x,y,z)` is an error while pattern matching against `List(x,y,z)` would only fail at runtime.